# How to extract schema information from PowerDesigner Sybase Server?

Tags: sql, metadata, sybase, powerdesigner

I have already created a query to extract metadata information including ModelName, ModelObject, TableName, ColumnName, DataType,Comments(Description)... from PowerDesigner Sever by using base tables such as PMRLSH, PMRLTN, PMCLSS,PMOBJT, PMCHCK, PMTEXT...

. I tried to join schema information to my metadata result too but I even cannot find the schema information at the first place. Any idea about this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure what you call "Schema information". Is it the information about the tables structure as they have been created in your server?

Comment: Yes, just like "dbo.", "etl."....etc and they have been created in my server.